# Validation for contract which has data which varies

Tags: smart-contract, randomness, validation

How does the EOS contract system handle data which varies? This could be from using a true random number, or receiving real-world data like a token price. Every time the contract executes, different values might be obtained, so I can see problems in consistent validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need information in your contract that changes over time, such as real-world pricing information, you should have an action on your contract that allows you to inject the information as part of a specific transaction.  Then, any subsequent actions called on the smart contract will use the injected information.  When the external information changes, a new transaction can be created to inject this new information.

This concept is generally called an [oracle](https://cointelegraph.com/explained/blockchain-oracles-explained).